# remove the current view and then navigate to another view in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, navigation

Is there a way to remove the current view and then go to another view in swiftui?

i dont want to navigate to the third view right away, i need to remove the current view before navigating to the third view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
              
                Text("1")

                NavigationLink(destination: Page2View()) {
                    Text("View Page 2")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .padding()

            
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Main Page")
        }
    }
}

struct Page2View: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Page 2")
            .navigationBarTitle("Page 2")
    }
}

struct Page3View: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Page 3")
            .navigationBarTitle("Page 3")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

i provided the simplest code to illustrate the issue

Comment: You can use if/else or switch

Comment: `if condition { View1() } else { View2() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

enum Path: Hashable {
    case page2
    case page3
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var navigationPath = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
            VStack {
                
                Text("1")
                
                Button(action: {
                    navigationPath.append(Path.page2)
                }, label: {
                    Text("View Page 2")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
                .padding()
                
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Main Page")
            .navigationDestination(for: Path.self) { path in
                switch path {
                case .page2: Page2View {
                    navigationPath.removeLast()
                    navigationPath.append(Path.page3)
                }
                case .page3: Page3View()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Page2View: View {
    var onClick: () -> ()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Page 2")
            .navigationBarTitle("Page 2")
        
        Button("Go to Page 3") {
            onClick()
        }
    }
}

struct Page3View: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Page 3")
            .navigationBarTitle("Page 3")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This code should do it, here's a breakdown:

- Enum Path: This enum defines the possible navigation destinations (page2 and page3).
- `@State var navigationPath`: This state variable holds the current navigation stack. Using this allows us to programmatically control the navigation, such as adding, removing, or replacing views.
- Navigation to Page 2: The Button in the main view appends Path.page2 to navigationPath, which results in navigation to Page2View. This is due to the `.navigationDestination(for:path:)` modifier that maps `Path.page2` to `Page2View`.
- Inside `Page2View`: This view takes a closure onClick as a parameter. This closure is for when the user wants to navigate from Page 2 to Page 3. Inside Page2View, there's a Button labeled "Go to Page 3" which, when tapped, will call the onClick closure.
- Navigating to Page 3: The onClick closure passed to `Page2View` is defined in the main view's `.navigationDestination(for:path:)` modifier for `Path.page2`. This closure first removes the last entry from navigationPath (which corresponds to `Page2View`) and then appends `Path.page3`, thereby navigating to `Page3View` and removing `Page2View` from the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Would I be right in understanding that you want to dismiss the current view, then go to a new view, all with animation?

I would suggest using a `NavigationStack` with a `path` for this, instead of a `NavigationView` (which is deprecated). Then pass a binding down to child views, to allow them to set the next view to go to.

To begin with, I tried performing navigation to the new view after a delay. I found that 1s was enough delay, but 0.5s was not. So I would suggest navigating to the view in `.onDisappear` instead. This avoids any unnecessary wait after going back to the root view and seems more reliable:

```swift
enum NavDestination {
    case page2
    case page3
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var navPath = [NavDestination]()
    @State private var nextView: NavDestination?

    private func goToNextViewIfSet() {
        if let nextView {
            navPath.append(nextView)
        }
        nextView = nil
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text("Page 1")
                NavigationLink(value: NavDestination.page2) {
                    Text("Go to Page 2")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Main Page")
            .navigationDestination(for: NavDestination.self) { navDestination in
                switch navDestination {
                case .page2:
                    Page2View(nextView: $nextView)
                        .onDisappear(perform: goToNextViewIfSet)
                case .page3:
                    Page3View(nextView: $nextView)
                        .onDisappear(perform: goToNextViewIfSet)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Page2View: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Binding var nextView: NavDestination?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("This is Page 2")
            Button("Go to Page 3") {
                nextView = .page3
                dismiss()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Page 2")
    }
}

struct Page3View: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Binding var nextView: NavDestination?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("This is Page 3")
            Button("Go to Page 2") {
                nextView = .page2
                dismiss()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Page 3")
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS 16.0+**

I'd suggest to use `NavigationStack(path: )` for navigation.

I'd suggest to add a simple `Router` class implementation to handle the whole navigation in your app more easily.

Check the following implementation:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

// MARK: This class will help you to navigate more easily
final class Router: ObservableObject {
    // Add the views you need to control
    public enum Destination: Codable, Hashable {
        case page2View
        case page3View
    }
    
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func navigate(to destination: Destination) {
        path.append(destination)
    }
    
    func navigateBack() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
    
    func navigateToRoot() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var router = Router()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.path) {
            // Wrap your main view inside a NavigationStack
            VStack {
                Text("1")
                NavigationLink(value: Router.Destination.page2View) {
                    Text("View Page 2")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .padding()

            
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Main Page")
            .navigationDestination(for: Router.Destination.self) { destination in
                // Handle navigation here
                switch destination {
                case .page2View: Page2View()
                case .page3View: Page3View()
                }
            }
            
        }.environmentObject(router)
    }
}

struct Page2View: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: Router
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is Page 2")
            
            Button(action: {
                router.navigateBack() // Pops the current view
            }, label: {
                Text("Remove View 2 and Show View 3")
            })
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Page 2")
        .onDisappear(perform: {
            router.navigate(to: .page3View) // Navigates to another view
        })
    }
}

struct Page3View: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Page 3")
            .navigationBarTitle("Page 3")
    }
}
```

**Output simulation:**

[image: Simulation]